# How to get the only direct child of a ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollview

One of my activities may contain different Fragment classes. Each of these fragment has a particular layout which can be a LinearLayout, a RelativeLayout or a ScrollView.
On this layout I would like to add a view programmatically. The problem is that, if the layout is a ScrollView I cannot add a view directly to it (I obtain the error `ScrollView can host only one direct child`). Then, if the fragment's layout is a ScrollView I would like to take that ONLY direct child (which is a LinearLayout or a RelativeLayout).

How can I take it? I tried with the following code

```
ViewGroup fragmentLayout = (ViewGroup)myFragment.getView();
if (fragmentLayout instanceof ScrollView)
    fragmentLayout = (ViewGroup)fragmentLayout.getChildAt(0);
```

but the returned child is not the one I am searching for.

Comment: what does it return and what are you expecting? paste your xml code for the layout too

Comment: you should give your layouts an id, and use `findById` on the `fragmentLayout`

Comment: It returns another child of the scrollview, but this one is not a direct child of the scrollview but a "nephew". I would like to avoid to assign an id, because I was searching for a more general solution (if there is one).

Answer (score 1):

ScrollView can have only one child. if you have a parrentview into your scrollview like relative or linear you can get what child you want with:

```
for(int i=0; i<((ViewGroup)v).getChildCount(); ++i) {
    View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)v).getChildAt(i);
}
```

where v is the parrentview

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you can get it just like other views/layouts with findViewById() and if the fragmentLayout is a ScrollView then you know that its child layout exists and you can handle it as you a normal layout...

Edit:
Ok, I just read in your comment, that you don't want to give ids, which I don't think is a good IDea. But in that case, why don't you leave the scrollView empty in your layout and add the child manually? Once you've noticed, it's a ScrollView, create a new LinearLayout (or whatever), add the view(s) that you would like and then add it to the scrollview...?

But I don't really see a good reason to not give it an id...?

Comment: I don't want to give an ID beacause I would like to have a general behaviour. I want to reuse that component (which is a drawer manager which loads fragments inside drawers) without having to remember that the inner child should have an id.